# How can I run a python file that uses other folders with files, without using the computer's path?

Tags: python, file, directory

My goal is to run a python file that uses files from a folder in the same folder as the python file, but regardless of the computer's path.

The situation I have now is that I have to define paths inside my code like: C:/Users/path/to/files/etc.

**The ideal situation would be if I could create a main folder (preferably a zip folder) with the python file in it, and also the necessary folders with files that the python file is using. That way I could sent the main folder to anyone and they should be able to run the python file.**

I am also using the os.listdir(C:/path/to/folder) function from the os library to import a whole folder, but this also works with the computer's path. So another alternative is needed.

Does anyone know how I could do this or at least something close to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get the directory in which the current Python file is using `abspath` and `dirname`:

```
this_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

And then you can construct your relative paths in a OS independent way using `join`:

```
some_image = os.path.join(this_dir, 'images', 'myimage.png')
```

Comment: You can use sys module in Standard library to add paths.

Comment: Can I also create paths to folders just like I did with: os.listdir(C:/path/to/folder) ?

Comment: And what does the second parameter in the os.path.join() function mean?

Comment: You just keep adding components of the path to it. So if you want to create a path relative from the current directory to `\a\b\c.txt` you would do `os.path.join('a', 'b', 'c.txt')`

Comment: And the explicit path you referenced would be `os.path.join('c:', os.sep, 'path', 'to', 'folder')`

Comment: And ```this_dir``` would be my main folder, correct?

Comment: Yes, `this_dir` was assigned to the result of `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` which is the absolute path to the directory containing the python script in which that line is executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use python script in another file which is located in a sub folder in the same directory. Did I get it right?
If it is you can just import it as

```
from <folder name> import <file name>
```